# How to Convert array of arrays into JSON using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a variable that is returning an array of arrays, with each item in each array in double quotes.

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
  [ "Name", "Age", "Address" ],
  [ "A", "43", "CA" ],
  [ "B", "23", "VA" ],
  [ "C", "24", "NY" ]
]
```

I need to convert this to the following:

```
var arrayOfObjects = [
  {"Name":"A", "Age":"43", "Address":"CA"},
  {"Name":"B", "Age":"23", "Address":"VA"},
  {"Name":"C", "Age":"24", "Address":"NY"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is simple demo.

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
  ["Name", "Age", "Address"],
  ["A", "43", "CA"],
  ["B", "23", "VA"],
  ["C", "24", "NY"]
];

function testConvert(arr) {
  var result = [];
  var keys = arr[0];
  
  for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = {};
    item[keys[0]] = arr[i][0];
    item[keys[1]] = arr[i][1];
    item[keys[2]] = arr[i][2];
    result.push(item);
  }
  
  return result;
}

console.log(testConvert(arrayOfArrays));
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract the headers and use the `map` function:

```
var headers = arrayOfArrays.splice(0,1)[0];

var arrayOfObjects = arrayOfArrays.map(function(e) {
   var o = {};
   headers.forEach(function(h, index) {
     o[h] = e[index];
   })

   return o;
});
```

Link [HERE](https://repl.it/G4HN/0).

Comment: How to make it dynamic? @AlonSegal